# Linear Regresssion: Multiple variables or build multiple models?

Tags: regression, linear

Hypothetical example: I want to regress a vehicle's fuel efficiency to the following variables:

1. Vehicle type (car, truck, van, SUV)
2. Year built
3. Weight
4. Manufacturer
5. Gas vs Diesel
6. etc..

When (if ever) would I split this 1 model to several models? For example, would it be wise to create 4 separate models: one for cars, trucks, vans and SUVs? You can assume I have a sufficient sample size after splitting.

If so, what are the best practices that would inform me to do this? Splitting would likely lead to a better model, as it would reduce noise.